# How to partition SD card on Android 4.1.1 using Linux?

Tags: external-sd, linux, partitions, link2sd, htc-desire-x

Hi I have a HTC Desire X and this device has a SD CARD with 16 Gb. I want to extend my memory using Link2D. I read I have to make partitions on my SD Card. The problem is that I do not know how. If I connect my phone in debugging mode with my Linux Mint laptop, it will connect with MTP and therefore I cannot use a partitioning tool. The Team Win Recovery Project Partitioning Tool (2.5) fails while partitioning the card and installing the app "APparted" or a busybox fail as well. How can I partition my SD card in the phone using Linux or Android?

The phone is rooted and SU is installed.

Answer (score 1):

Is this an external SD card?  If so, you can simply remove it from the SD card slot, and use either an SD card reader on the laptop, which may be built in, or you can get a cheap adapter that takes an SD card, and acts like a USB drive.  I've seen them on Amazon for as little as $2.25 including shipping, or nicer ones for $5 - $10.  Search for "sd card reader" to see.

Then, you can use gparted to partition it.  Just make sure to use the correct filesystem(s).

Comment: Yes it is an external SD Card and actually I wanted to avoid it to buy an adapter.

Comment: I have several that came with the sd cards. They can be useful, especially if you decide to simply use the extra memory for media files; you can have multiple cards, and set them up on the desktop for later use in the phone.  It's also faster, I believe.

Comment: @IrgendwPointer I would advise against partitioning in the phone, or even in most built-in laptop SD Card readers.  Many of those don't properly write partition tables, and will corrupt the card, requiring another round of re-partitioning. A basic stand-alone SD Card reader is heaps more reliable.